# Custom GUI for libmpv

Tags: c#, video-player, mpv

i'm trying to create a custom GUI for libmpv (that uses mpv(. I will be using libmpv from C#.

Any pointers/samples/tutorials how to create one?

The exsamples that mpv has/i have found/, do not contain anything related. What i'm trying to create, for starters, is a custom "window" that pops up when mouse is moved over the video window/key is pressed. I would like this window to contain basic seek bar and playback controls.

Cheers
-k

Comment: Very generic query - Google for Video Player Images and pick anyone that you like. Its going to be fun to create UserControls for your liking. WPF comes with a MediaPlayer class that can do both Audio & Video playback (limited video formats only).

Comment: Hi, i tried to google it, without luck. Hence i'm here. Tried to add 'libmpv' as tag, to narrow it down, but there isn't one.

Comment: any updates? I am trying to build a macOS app that use libmpv as well (smiliar to IINA but not the same)